# QML fillWidth updates only when resized

Tags: qml

I have a problem with Layout.fillWidth property in the following code:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0

RowLayout {
    spacing: 40

    Rectangle {
        color:"#39c605"
        height:width
        Layout.fillWidth: true

    }
    Rectangle {
        color:"#39c605"
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        height:width
    }

    Rectangle {
        color:"#39c605"
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        height:width
    }
}
```

I can see the rectangles only when I change size of the window, but it'n't visible when the app is started.

Help me, please, to resolve this issue

Add:
main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
import "pages/"

ApplicationWindow {
    id:mainWindows
    visible: true
    width:1280
    height:720
    title:qsTr("abc")
    Material.theme: Material.Light
    Material.accent: Material.LightGreen
    Material.primary: Material.Blue
    StackView {
        id:homeView
        anchors.fill: parent

        initialItem:DataList{
        }
    }
}
```

QT 5.8

Comment: Please provide real code. In this code you didn't define size for `RowLayout` so nothing will be shown at all. Also you set `height` to `width` but at app start width is 0. `Layout` will do its work after all components already initialized.

Comment: You didn't set a sizing policy on the layout itself. What's the behaviour if you set `anchors.fill: true` on the layout?

Comment: folibis, I'm sorry, I've added it.
BaCaRoZzo, it's set in the parent element

Comment: So the first code block defines `DataList`? And where is your `Layout`? Maybe you meant to use `StackLayout` instead of the `StackView`?

Comment: Yes, it's DataList, sorry. Ooops, it's my fault...yeah, it's should be Layout, thank you